# filter data with php or sql?

Tags: php, sql, api, random

I'm not sure if this is an anti-pattern or not, but it feels a bit convoluted, so I'd like to get your opinion on how these cases should be handled:

Let's say we have this data:

```
$sofas[0]['color'] = 'green';
$sofas[0]['pillows'] = 8;
$sofas[0]['pattern'] = 'moons';

$sofas[1]['color'] = 'green';
$sofas[1]['pillows'] = 8;
$sofas[1]['pattern'] = 'ducks';
$sofas[1]['footrest'] = 'small';

$sofas[2]['color'] = 'green';
$sofas[2]['pillows'] = 8;
$sofas[2]['pattern'] = 'stripes';
$sofas[2]['speakers'] = 'badass';
```

color, pillows and pattern comes from the database, whilst "footrest" and "speakers" have been added on by an api.

We can say for the sake of argument that there are 1250 different attributes that can be added by the api like "footrest" and "speakers".

We now want to load an some data from the database based on these attributes, like an image for example.

So we have a table that looks like this:

```
ID , attribute_value, image
1  , 'color_green'    'img0023',
2  , 'pillows_8'      'img003',
3  , 'pattern_moons'  'img002',
6  , 'pattern_ducks'  'img0083',
7  , 'footrest_small' 'img0058',
10 , 'pattern_stripes''img0073',
11 , 'speakers_badass''img00pluto'
```

etc ,  etc , etc;

So, the way I figure I can approach this two ways:

```
$sofaSQL="'color_green',
'pillows_8',
'pattern_moons',
'pattern_ducks',
'footrest_small',
'pattern_stripes',
'speakers_badass'";

$sql = "SELECT ID, attribute_value, image 
       FROM `example` 
       WHERE attribute_value IN ($sofaSQL)"
```

and then loop through the array and check if the key + '_' + value matches the rows in the recordset to see what images should be used for sofas[0], sofas[1] and sofas[2].

The other option I see would be to prep each sofa with a different sql statement, ie:

```
$sofaSQL="'color_green',
'pillows_8',
'pattern_moons';
```

-add images-

```
$sofaSQL="'color_green',
'pillows_8',
'pattern_ducks',
'footrest_small';
```

-add images-

```
$sofaSQL="'color_green',
'pillows_8',
'pattern_stripes',
'speakers_badass'";
```

-add images-

That seems simpler, but it doesn't feel right to hammer the database with a seperate request for each item in the array.

So, what would you recommend in this case? IS there a better way of dealing with attributes that are selected randomly/from an api?

Comment: It all depends on why you do this, and what you do with the result. There's absolutely no context to your question. Ok, you find images for sofas, but when do you this? When a new sofa is entered into the system? Do you not store the results?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
It's for an xml page, so it's essentially for an API that is being used quite often for every user.

No, I'm not storing the results, because in the actual enviroment there might be anywhere from 15 to 20 of these addon attributes that are being pulled in, and with some 1250 different atributes to chose from there would simply be too many different variations.

if it has 20 addon attributes it'd be something like 7,4446E+61 entries, and quite frankly, I don't think any SQL engine can handle that.

Comment: I still don't get the context. I don't care it is an XML page or an API, that's not context. What I have a problem with is that you seem to search for images associated with sofas. Call me stupid but I would think that it would be quite clear with images belong with which sofas. Why is this problem so random? As to your question: The normal advise would be to try both, but my guess is that processing the data in PHP will be faster than multiple queries.

Comment: Oh, well that's probably my fault for simplifying the problem too much - the images are sprites on a sprite sheet and it isn't the only thing that is being loaded, it also loads x y values which is then used to build the final image of the sofa.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: And thanks, I figgured proccessing it with php would be the route to go.

Comment: Ah, so you create an image of a sofa given certain criteria. Yes, that makes more sense (although I can't see how that would work). Good luck with it. But as always: If someone asks "How best to dig a hole?", then the obvious response would be "Which hole, and why?".